Running from command line, how can I automatically affirm dialog prompt?
I am running a Windows application from the command line (PowerShell/Command Prompt):
.\myapp.exe <some arguments>

When the app starts, it displays a dialog similar to this:

I want to be able to respond Yes to this dialog prompt from the command line, i.e. without having to manually click on the Yes button. Is there anything I can add to my command line, e.g. pipe input or PowerShell/Command Prompt options, to automatically respond to the dialog and close it?

i think your app.exe should have code for switch..say /silent..then you can pass it... you can see entire arguments using app.exe $?

Unfortunately, the app I am running does not list its arguments. I have tested /silent and /quiet, but they are not recognized.

Generally speaking: By default, you cannot avoid UAC dialogs that are presented when elevation (running as an administrator with elevated privileges) is requested. The only workarounds are insecure and therefore strongly discouraged - see this answer. The best solution is to call from an already-elevated process (which just shifts the point in time when a UAC dialog must be responded to).

The UAC will come always, try to run this in admin, right click run as admin or change the app executable or the apps entire folder and give it all elevated administrator permissions. Then UAC prompt will be skipped, or if you as I can see are already using Auto Hotkey, there are many scripts available for this, where it automatically clicks Yes (Button 1) when it detected the UAC admin prompt, you can activate it keeps running on loop and that's good for you, or if you can, disable UAC, [DON'T, this is last resort.]

Unfortunately, it does not help to run as admin, the UAC prompt displays anyway. I am not using AutoHotKey, it just happened to be the first image to show up when I googled for similar images. I'll add a note on this in the question.

Oh, You should have clarified that, but anyways you should try and use AutoHotKey, i used it in a Windows VM some time ago for running vbs for some work and it does work, give it a go.

While AutoHotkey is a capable GUI scripting language, one can only hope that it doesn't support automating responses to UAC dialogs, specifically, as this would amount to a serious security vulnerability.
